# how to retrieve value from both parent and child checkbox checked

Tags: jquery, checkbox

i am having this issue i have the code for both checked parent and child. but the problem is i dunno how to retrieve the value in the end.. here the checkbox list that include both parent and child

```
<ul id="jobCat">
        <li>
            <input id="s9" class="parent" type="checkbox" name="jobCat" value="Accounting / Finance"
            />Accounting / Finance</li>
        <li>
            <input id="s15" class="parent-s9" type="checkbox" name="jobCat" value="Banking / Financial"
            /><span>Banking / Financial</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input id="s16" class="parent-s9" type="checkbox" name="jobCat" value="General / Cost Acct"
            /><span>General / Cost Acct</span>
        </li> </ul>
```

---

and here the jquery

```
 var checkboxHandlerObj = {

    init: function () {
        $('#jobCat input:checkbox[class="parent"]').click(checkboxHandlerObj.parentClicked);
        $('#jobCat input:checkbox[class^="parent-"]').click(checkboxHandlerObj.childClicked);
    },
    parentClicked: function () {
        var parentCheck = this.checked;
        $('#jobCat input:checkbox[class="parent-' + $(this).attr('id') + '"]').each(function () {
            this.checked = parentCheck;
        });
    },
    childClicked: function () {
        var temp = $(this).attr('class').split('-');
        var parentId = temp[1];
        $('#' + parentId)[0].checked = $('#jobCat input:checkbox[class="' + $(this).attr('class') + '"]:checked').length !== 0;
    }
};

checkboxHandlerObj.init();
```

here.. after i click Accounting/ Financial checkbox, it selected all. but that doesnt show the value in the end so what i want is i want to show all of them (both parent and child) in the end. i am confusing how to code for that.. please help me anyone..

Answer (score 0):

please have a look at fiddle. this may give you some idea how to do that..

http://jsfiddle.net/Gy9Jq/

you need to change below function:

```
 parentClicked: function () {
        var parentCheck = this.checked;
        var values='i';
        $('#jobCat input:checkbox[class="parent-' + $(this).attr('id') + '"]').each(function () {
            this.checked = parentCheck;
            values+=this.attr('value');
        });
        alert('hi');
    },
```

check updated fiddle here.i think this is what u want:

http://jsfiddle.net/Gy9Jq/6/

Comment: you can  edit within there only. here im storing all values in single variable i.e. values just for example sake. you need to modify if you need.

Comment: actually i want the value to show in the end like after checked all, the answer show Accounting/ Finance 
Banking ...
General/ .... something like that

Comment: i got it like it.. but there is some issue.. let's say if i click `general/cost acc` **general/cost acc**  it show 2times at the end.. how could i change into only one line? i mean i only want to show only `general/cost acc`